# How to Customize a multiple Select box using CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to customize a single selection box with multiple open options using only CSS? I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find any immediate joy :( My code will be adding options to a select box based on searches but for simplicity sake, I've just inserted that sample to show what it will look like. Was wondering if you could change the background-color, color when hovered, animations etc.

```html
<div id="album">
<select id="albumPicker" size="5">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting to style each option individually, give each option an id and in your CSS code style the option element just like you would any other element.

```html
<style>
#option1{
    color:blue;
    background:red;
}
#option1:hover{
    color:red;
    background:blue;
}
</style>
<div id="album">
<select id="albumPicker" size="5">
  <option id="option1">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% that this can be done using strictly CSS. I have used jQuery plugins such as [Selectric](http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/) in the past to accomplish this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you may be able to accomplish this using the `:nth-child` pseudo class.

For example:

```
#albumPicker option:nth-child(2n+2){
  background-color: red;
}
```

This will select every other `option` field, starting with the second `option`. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qpka2n8/) to demonstrate.